# null tag bug on Super User?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/80556/how-do-you-view-all-threads-running-on-linux), as of this moment, has a "null" tag. There are four tag "buttons": linux, tools, "null", and threads.

"Retag" simply shows two spaces between "tools" and "threads".

Didn't try to fix it to allow troubleshooting.

Comment: It's a known issue. You can delete the empty tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19013/empty-tag-when-migrating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tag was `belongs-on-serverfault` when the question was [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868640/how-do-you-view-all-threads-running-on-linux-closed). Apparently something went wrong with the auto-removal of `belongs-on-*` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Jeff is stripping out the "belongs-on-" tags that questions have before they get migrated which is creating an empty tag.

This might get fixed by the daily vote sync script.

Comment: They've been stripped out for some time, but I've never seen one turn into a blank tag before.

Comment: @mmyers, ah, I have never noticed that. I'd hope this isn't being caused because it was tagged as belongs-on-serverfault but instead migrated to SuperUser. :P